# Download a thubnails of an image using Dropbox API for php

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I made a script where I download the images from a dropbox folder to my computer using PHP.
What I try to do now is to download thumbnail of the images instead of the whole image.
For this I use the: GetThumbNail method from the Dropbox API.
Here is part of the code:

```
    // download the files
    $f = fopen($img_name, "w+b");   
    $fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getThumbnail($path, 'jpeg','xl');
    fclose($f);
```

When I run this the images I get are 0 size and they have no content. Any ideas what I am missing?
Thanks
D.

**EDITED**

```
    $f = fopen($img_name, 'w+b');
    $thumbnailData = $dbxClient->getThumbnail($path, 'jpeg', 'xl');
    fwrite($f, $thumbnailData);
    fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening and closing `$f` without ever writing anything into it.

[`getThumbnail`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_getThumbnail) returns an array with two elements: the metadata for the file and the thumbnail data.

So I think you'll want something like this:

```
$f = fopen($img_name, 'w+b');
list($fileMetadata, $thumbnailData) = $dbxClient->getThumbnail($path, 'jpeg', 'xl');
fwrite($f, $thumbnailData);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The quotes in $img_name in the firstline is a mistake right? And also in the second line the $fileMetadata shouldn't exist. I don't understand why it still doesn't work. It just creates images with 0 KB. I edited my answer with the code I use now after your answer.

Comment: Yup, sorry fixed. Why do you say "the $fileMetadata shouldn't exist"? With your current code, I would expect you to maybe end up with a file with some sort of serialized version of the metadata in it.

Comment: Or maybe even a serialized version of both the metadata and the contents? (`getThumbnail` returns an array in which the first element is the metadata for the file and the second element is the thumbnail contents. I guess your code will end up passing that array to fwrite, and I don't know what that will do.)

Comment: Aaa I see now what you mean. Hmmm But when I use your code I get an error.

Comment: I just updated the code again. My syntax was wrong on the second line... I think you need `list(...)` on the left-hand side of the assignment.