# Use imagick and php to create a thumbnail of an image which is in dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox-api, imagick

I have installed imageMagick and imagick for php and I played with it a bit. I made some thumbnails of images etc.
What I want to do is to use it to make a thumbnail of image, which is located inside dropbox.
I wonder if this is possible.
Something like this:

```
      $thumb = new Imagick($path);
      $thumb->resizeImage(50,50,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
      $thumb->writeImage('C:\pic.jpg');
```

Where the $path is the directory to the image located inside dropbox. I have used the Dropbox API to connect to dropbox and see all my files there but my question is how to get an absolute path which I can use in my object $thumb? Is this possible?

Thanks 
Dimitris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are access the data over HTTP then there won't be a file system path for you to use. You'll need to use the API to [get the file over HTTP](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) and then either save it in a temporary location or pass the data directly to ImageMagick.

You could use a file path if you were accessing the files from your local disk and syncing them with the regular dropbox application in the background.

Comment: So you mean that in any case I have to download the files, right? I do this now but it doesn't help as the images size is quite big and it takes time. Alternatively I tried to use the GetThumbnail method of the API but it doesn't work. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344561/download-a-thubnails-of-an-image-using-dropbox-api-for-php

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a URL directly into ImageMagick, like this:

```
  $thumb = new Imagick("http://skyscan.co.uk/la/79067.jpg");
  $thumb->resizeImage(50,50,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
  $thumb->writeImage('out.jpg');
```

[image]